# Trying to connect to onedrives API

Tags: bash, jenkins, onedrive

I am trying to integrate some of my current Jenkins jobs with one-drives API in order to post files from Jenkins to a shared one-drive folder.  however I am having an issue authenticating into one drive, my bash script is listed below:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Define your variables
CLIENT_ID="<>"
CLIENT_SECRET="<>"
TENANT_ID="<>"
# Define the folder where your Jenkins instance stores the files
SOURCE_FOLDER="/Users/<>/Desktop/TEST"

# Define the folder path in OneDrive where you want to upload the files
ONEDRIVE_FOLDER_PATH=""

# Authenticate and obtain an access token
TOKEN_RESPONSE=$(curl -X POST "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANT_ID/oauth2/token" \
     -d "client_id=$CLIENT_ID" \
     -d "client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET" \
     -d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
     -d "scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default")

# Extract the access token from the JSON response
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(echo "$TOKEN_RESPONSE" | jq -r '.access_token')

if [ -z "$ACCESS_TOKEN" ]; then
    echo "Failed to obtain an access token."
    exit 1
fi

# Loop through files in the source folder and upload them to OneDrive
for FILE in "$SOURCE_FOLDER"; do
    FILE_NAME=$(basename "$FILE")
    ONEDRIVE_API_URL="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:$ONEDRIVE_FOLDER_PATH/$FILE_NAME:/content"
    ONEDRIVE_API_URL="https://$TENANT_ID.sharepoint.com/CRM/_api/v2.0/drive/root:$ONEDRIVE_FOLDER_PATH/$FILE_NAME:/content"

    # Calculate the content length of the file
    CONTENT_LENGTH=$(wc -c < "$FILE")

    # Use curl to upload the file to OneDrive with the "Content-Length" header
    UPLOAD_RESPONSE=$(curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" -H "Content-Length: $CONTENT_LENGTH" --upload-file "$FILE" "$ONEDRIVE_API_URL")

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "File '$FILE_NAME' uploaded to OneDrive successfully."
    else
        echo "Failed to upload file '$FILE_NAME' to OneDrive."
    fi
done

# Exit with success
exit 0
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

> {"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.","innerError":{"date":"2023-09-28T14:25:58","request-id":"<>","client-request-id":"<>"}}}

Comment: This seems related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/993291/microsoft-graph-api-error-access-token-validation
Good luck!

Comment: #1 Did you try the token generation with some http client like  postman before try it with bash or jenkins? #2 Is it a personal (hotmail, skype, outlook, etc) or a company account?

Answer (score 0):

The error is not related to onedrive. You have an authentication error

### Create account and credentials

Use this url to get the token exchanging the clientid/clientsecret:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/token

### Detailed explanation

I validated with a new account. These are the steps to get a token from the scratch:

#1 Go to [https://entra.microsoft.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade/quickStartType~/null/sourceType/Microsoft_AAD_IAM](https://entra.microsoft.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade/quickStartType%7E/null/sourceType/Microsoft_AAD_IAM) (Applications > App Registrations)

[image]

This will change slightly if you use a company account instead a personal

#2 Find your App that you want the Client ID for

[image]

#3 In Overview you will find the Client ID:

[image]

#4 Navigate to Certificates & secrets:

#5 Click New client secret and generate a new secret to use

[image]

[image]

### Get the token

Configure an http client following the oauth2 spec

https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/

**Postman**

[image]

**Curl**

```
curl --location 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=1a57b0e1-fe22-415a-9aa8-149309fc17f5' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=5@Q9iT0by54NM4B#UQTdx9OHpeG#PReEIgRrnj07' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
```

> Note: the clientid and client secret are just examples. Use your own values

> For enterprises, use the tenant-id instead of "consumers" in the token url